# Permission to manage Current Navigation

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, navigation, current-navigation

I use a limited permission set for the owners of the sites (aka Site Admins). I do not give them permission to create subsites, lists, apps, etc. due to issues we have had in the past. I recently discovered that unless someone is given permission to manage lists, they cannot edit the Current Navigation links on the site. Is there a more "fine-grained" permission setting for this rather than allowing them to create and delete lists?

SharePoint Online

Answer (score 2):

In fact to manage a SharePoint site's navigation, one must have either **Full Control** or **Design** level permissions for the site ([source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Understanding-permission-levels-in-SharePoint-87ecbb0e-6550-491a-8826-c075e4859848)). As both of these are high-level permissions, it would likely lead to extreme permission level policy where many of the contents would have unique permissions. Even if that would be well managed, it would still be poorly administrable.

I can only come with a workaround, where you'd define your managed as Managed Navigation based on a term set. With term sets you can define term set contributors who have the permissions to manage terms, which in your case could be navigation's links. The drawback with this is the manually updated navigation and another permission group to take into account. For more information, see [Assign roles and permissions to manage term sets](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Assign-roles-and-permissions-to-manage-term-sets-951216b9-81ac-4850-9ea0-7ad4c45eb231).

I understand there are scenarios where your requirement is very much requested, but allow me to throw my 2¢. If I wouldn't be able to trust my users to correctly handle lists (not to mention any "bigger" SharePoint's content areas) - which is a relatively normal case - , I wouldn't let them configure the navigation either.

Comment: Although an interesting approach - it almost seems impractical to get the users to understand how that works.. It works and is a viable solution for other people, not sure if I could pull that off here. I upvoted, but I will give it some time and see if I get any other angles. I really do not like how I find myself always hacking around SharePoint like this to do simple things (such as no good way to redirect to the submitted item on a form)!